# Files disappear When moved to desktop

Tags: unity

I was in my home folder and I moved my `.minecraft` folder to the desktop and it disappeared!
I know it is still because if i create a new folder called .minecraft on the desktop, it says I can't do that because there is already a folder called that on the desktop.
I have very little Ubuntu experience and I am running 12.04 unity.

Do you have any idea of how to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, folders and files starting with a dot are not displayed by default. A `ls -al` will show them in the terminal. In many GUIs, `ctrl-H` will show the hidden files. For the Desktop, I am not so sure (I use Xfce4). I can assure you that the folder is in you ~/Desktop, it is just not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Files starting with `.` are hidden files. If you create a file with `.` Ubuntu hides that file. You can view hidden files from terminal and in Nautilus File manager.

From Nautilus file manager: press

```
ctrl+h
```

It will be temporary after you close nautilus file manager it will be back to default hidden.

To make it permanent : open nautilus file manager

goto edit -> preferences -> in views select `show hidden files and backup`

From Terminal: go to the directory where file is there and enter

> cd ~/Desktop
>
> ls -a